# Asynchronous property in Servlet 3.0 testing query

Tags: java, multithreading, jsp, servlets, asynchronous

I have implemented Asynchronous property in Servlet 3.0 using below tutorial.

http://hmkcode.com/java-servlet-3-0-asynchronous-support/

After implementing a runnable class at back-end, I have observed that the 2 threads are created and one ends up in asynchronous manner and other does back-end processing. I was able to implement successfully the mentioned Asynchronous property.
In the runnable class, I have kept a sleep of 25 seconds and I have tried using outStream.println(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()) in the servlet class, I have observed a deviation.The time value which is printed in println is the time when the request started but the outStream is printed on the URL hit page after 25 seconds.
I just want to understand when print was framed within servlet (based on time-stamp I came to this analysis), why is it printed in servlet URL hit page after worker class sleep time.

```
 @WebServlet(name="asyncServlet",value = {"/async"},asyncSupported = true)       
public class AsyncServlet extends HttpServlet 
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Override
protected void handleRequest(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
servletoutputstream out = response.getoutputstream(); 
   final AsyncContext ctx = req.startAsync();
 ctx.addListener(new AsyncListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeout(AsyncEvent arg0) throws IOException {
            System.out.println("onTimeout...");             
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartAsync(AsyncEvent arg0) throws IOException {
            System.out.println("onStartAsync...");              
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(AsyncEvent arg0) throws IOException {
            System.out.println("onError...");           
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(AsyncEvent arg0) throws IOException {
            System.out.println("onComplete...");
        }
   });
   ctx.start(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
             try {
        Thread.currentThread.sleep(1000);

            } catch InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

         ctx.complete();
        }
   });
    out.write("Got the request"+calendar.getinstance().gettimeinmillis());
out.close();
}
}
```

Here I am printing out, the time captured in out string is before the sleep time yet it is printed in after sleep time.

I have tried with PrintWriter, yet same output is observed.
Is there any way to print the response before sleep time using above code.

Comment: Can you  post your code ?

Comment: Guys...some one please help, I am unable to send response back to server in asynchronous manner using above code. Motto is to send response asynchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the code that works as you want.

```
     @WebServlet(name = "asyncServlet", value = { "/async" }, asyncSupported = true)
public class AsyncServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
    final   PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 

        final AsyncContext ctx = req.startAsync();
        ctx.addListener(new AsyncListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeout(AsyncEvent arg0) throws IOException {
                System.out.println("onTimeout...");             
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartAsync(AsyncEvent arg0) throws IOException {
                System.out.println("onStartAsync...");              
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(AsyncEvent arg0) throws IOException {
                System.out.println("onError...");           
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(AsyncEvent arg0) throws IOException {
                System.out.println("onComplete...");
                out.close();
            }
        });
        ctx.start(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                }catch(InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    out.print("<br> Got the request : "+Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()+" For Async thread :"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    out.flush();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                ctx.complete();
            }
        });
        try {
            long time=Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
            out.print("<br>Got the request :"+time+" For Original thread completed :"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            out.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

output :

```
Got the request :1426238802101 For Original thread completed :http-bio-8080-exec-14
```

After 3 seconds:

```
 Got the request : 1426238805101 For Async thread :http-bio-8080-exec-9
```

[Click here](https://github.com/rajeevshukla/AsynServlet) to see a  demo project which contains details code of  Asynchronous Servlet.

Comment: I see that after publishing first print, the servlet page is still in loading states until 3 seconds sleep is completed. Can we do anything that even that loading status is also changed?

Comment: Servlet will be in loading state because of data coming from server asynchronously even if first request has been completed  . Generally we use asynchronous behavior using ajax technique. Use Firebug and then you can understand behavior very well.

Comment: oh, so though it does processing asynchronously, we cannot get the response in async. I believe then we should use this API just for backend Asynchronous processing but not for sending response as well in Async manner. Is there any API which can does both?